# Unable to sign GitHub commit from Eclipse

Tags: git, eclipse, git-commit, gnupg, egit

I am trying to sign my commits, from Eclipse IDE, using GPG (as implemented by Git). I have generated the keys, updated the necessary configuration, bot on my computer and GitHub, but I can not get the process to work. Keep in mind that the commit process works ok from eclipse, as long as I do not enable signing (no problem with github setup).

If I enable the signing, in Eclipse, the process starts, it asks me for the password for the key but after that I get an error (showed in Eclipse details):

```
An internal error occurred
External program failed ([GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 1828 w32 1.2.1-unknown - xterm-256color - - 197609/197609 0
[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED D 1 8 00 1700211085 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C
): C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe -bsau B08D503E442EBB5C --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --output -
```

If I run the command `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe -bsau B08D503E442EBB5C --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --output -` straight into GitBash, is it working ok, as I get the following output

```
cosmi@Terra MINGW64 ~
$ "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe" -bsau B08D503E442EBB5C --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --output -
[GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
this is the content that will be signed
another row
[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED D 1 8 00 1700211486 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
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=wi4U
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

cosmi@Terra MINGW64 ~
```

What I tried so far:

- read a lot of data about Eclipse and signing, found nothing about this particular case
- is does not matter if git is using mingw64 or windows terminal
- it does not matter if I am using Git or Gpg4win
- it does not matter what algorithm I am using for the key (right now I am using RSA)

What am I suspecting: The Git/GPG installation is ok, there is a problem with the way Eclipse is reading the output from gpg.exe.

Any help will be appreciated.

LE

After mode digging, I can see that the key is generared, but Eclipse says that is it invalid. Below is the error log from Eclipse.

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException: External program failed ([GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 541 w32 1.2.1-unknown - xterm-256color - - 197609/197609 0
[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED D 1 8 00 1704551695 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C
): C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe -bsau <<hidden>@<hidden>.com> --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --output -
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.signObject(ExternalGpgSigner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.sign(CommitCommand.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.call(CommitCommand.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.commit(CommitOperation.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation$1.run(CommitOperation.java:211)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2453)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2478)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.CommitOperation.execute(CommitOperation.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.commit.CommitJob.run(CommitJob.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: External program failed ([GNUPG:] KEY_CONSIDERED 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C 2
[GNUPG:] BEGIN_SIGNING H8
[GNUPG:] PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 541 w32 1.2.1-unknown - xterm-256color - - 197609/197609 0
[GNUPG:] SIG_CREATED D 1 8 00 1704551695 9AFFDDDAA380771D16313B11B08D503E442EBB5C
): C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe -bsau <<hidden>@<hidden>> --batch --no-tty --status-fd 2 --output -
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.runProcess(ExternalGpgSigner.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.signWithGpg(ExternalGpgSigner.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.signObject(ExternalGpgSigner.java:189)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: External GPG did not return a valid signature; got: -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----

iQHLBAABCAA1FiEEmv/d2qOAdx0WMTsRsI1QPkQuu1wFAmWZZQ8XHGNvc21pbnN0
YWljdUBnbWFpbC5jb20ACgkQsI1QPkQuu1wYVAwAko5/T/oip+ix1wufJFmJVST3
FtT3Z2J1Oai5i18RYCWtTIShAKLZ6UlN9tOjTw8fcz0ljTvWnfojWW4zyz80ztCL
zn8n1nSWZmrwC0xv28QogL6sV7oRkln3+zqh49wavw3afIucicaGcSHhUG+vkPtt
zC7JscyGlDaJjg5wFGV3/AEfwf4u5JN1bZCecrxGvjVySjpRl5YHAEP/bJv4MGA3
6i2Deny//j6l4ht2o1eKEHlxxWay1We0YTGOiR50zKni5EAu2zddQ8Wbh15iGGbO
+EMdD3mii+dILDMRgTedDRBeHhaY+QWyiwRnIfQ1ifsIsJvwVPYNlIHUs4Wil5y1
I2bh4cZzzHZweq8CWh8ZYwkzEikXrNAW23k6xVOnIFBsJ5c8HudF4Ml5CY4sS9LL
g14Jd1+hgX96q4oK9dgv5mvHkWXAOj/E6cDVSJO/iZCEe7HjRw/DbfE636GvIfMg
qGDb2Hh5rVfXf7cZa2JbBXacpBh2Ics5ik4BkrsW
=DIGl
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.lambda$1(ExternalGpgSigner.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.signing.ExternalGpgSigner.runProcess(ExternalGpgSigner.java:110)
    ... 11 more
```

As you can see, it says

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: External GPG did not return a valid signature; got: -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

No ideea how to move further.

Comment: Eclipse does not need the Git installation. If you want to use `gpg.exe` rather than the _Bouncy Castle library_, you have to configure it in the preferences. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.11#Using_GPG_to_Sign_Commits_and_Tags

Comment: I have no personal preferences between GPG and Bouncy Castle. I used GIT for creating the GPG keys. But, if I choose Bouncy Castle for signing, Eclipse just says that there are no keys available, to sign the commit. If I choose gpg.exe, then the signature is generated (I can see it in the logs), but Eclipse says that the signature is not valid.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Still unable to figure out the solution. The same gpg key works when I commit from command line, but eclipse does not work. Note: I am using the the same gpg installation for both eclipse and comand line, i.e: C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe.
I have tried with the gpg that comes with Git's installation but with no luck. It seems some issue with Eclipse. 
Note: I am using Eclipse 2023-12 with everything up to date.
If you hve found the solution, please share.

Comment: @Kazi It worked for me. GPG have to be configured either via Git config or via Eclipse preferences (see my first comments).

Comment: @howlget Still unable to sign. Eclipse is set up ok, as it asks me for the password to the gpg key (that is an external interface, provided by gpg.exe) so the config is ok. Also, it creates the signing key, I can see the generated signature in Eclipse error log. But Eclipse says that the signature is invalid. I will update the question with the error log.

Comment: The error message [`External GPG did not return a valid signature; got:`](https://github.com/eclipse-egit/egit/blob/eb2608bbb27d0976fd73566aa423b42df20bc91b/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/internal/coretext.properties#L52) is [thrown here](https://github.com/eclipse-egit/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/core/internal/signing/ExternalGpgSigner.java#L327). If and only if you can reproduce it with the latest EGit version, make sure it has been reported with a minimal reproducible example to EGit, best with a pull request that fixes the issue.

Comment: There is an open issue on GitHub with this problem: https://github.com/eclipse-egit/egit/issues/12

Comment: An EGit developer has already responded. Can you or someone who faces the issue verify what was said (e.g. by checking and telling whether it works if you (temporarily) rename `%APPDATA%\gnupg`)? Please reply to the issue. /cc @Kazi